# cakephp $this- auth- identify() return false

Tags: cakephp

please i really need help i tried almost everything on forums

The method $this->Auth->identify(); always return false

the length fo password in database is varchar(255)

my cakephp version is 3.6.8

candidatcontroller

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
        $candidat = $this->Auth->identify(); 
        if ($candidat) 
        {
            $this->Auth->setUser($candidat);
            return $this->redirect(['Controller'=>'Candidat','action'=>'index']);
        }
     $this->Flash->error(__('The candidat could not be saved Please try again.'));
    }
}
```

appcontroller

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
        'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
    ]);
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authError' => 'Vous croyez vraiment que vous pouvez faire cela?',
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => ['username' => 'email','password' => 'password']
        ]
    ],
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'candidat',
        'action' => 'login',
    ],
    'storage' => 'Session'
    ]);

}
```

login

```
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('login') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('Email_cand',['label'=>'Email']);
        echo $this->Form->control('password',['label'=>'mot de passe']);
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('connecter')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Comment: change the email form field to **$this->Form->control('Email_cand',['name' => 'email','label'=>'Email']);**

Comment: did not work the email form disappeared

Comment: $this->Form->control('email',['label'=>'Email']);

Comment: aslo did not work the same prob returning false

Comment: What are the names of the database columns you're using for your "username" and password?

Comment: did you hashed your password ? Share your model code.

Comment: I think you have to tell cake that you are using candidat table and not users table for authentication. Try to add `'userModel' => 'Candidat'` as explained [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)

Comment: in the data base :    username : Email_cand       password: password

Comment: i hashed my password 
protected function _setPassword($value)
    {
        if (strlen($value)) {
            $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();

            return $hasher->hash($value);
        }
    }

Comment: it worked thank you arilia i needed to add 'userModel' => 'Candidat'
thank you guys

Comment: @zakaria, could you create an a answer for yourself and mark it? Thanks